# How to read GigaThread global scheduler?

Tags: cuda, gpgpu, gpu

Is it possible to access the code of GigaThread global scheduler?

My intention is to know how many SMs are employed by the scheduler at a given instant (upon the assumption that GigaThread global scheduler is the scheduler responsible to decide how many SMs and which SMs in particular need to be employed for a particular application). So is there any way by which I can make the scheduler maintain a log and update it everytime it employs a new set of SMs for an application with the number of SMs or the IDs of the SMs for me?

This will help me look into the log file to check how many SMs were employed recently by the scheduler whenever I need the information.

Comment: please stop asking the same thing over and over again.

Comment: And don't tag your question OpenCL when it's got nothing to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no exposed method to trace the compute work distributor.

It is possible to instrument kernel code to collect this information using %smid and %clock. This can be done on a per warp or per thread block basis.

The compute work distributor attempts to keep all SMs busy.

Comment: Where is the compute work distributor source code present?

Comment: Using %smid means I have to run a program for that on gpu. If some program is already running it won't allow my program to run concurrently. So I need to do something outside the context scene. Tracing scheduler seems difficult.

Comment: The compute work distributor is not programmable. If you benchmark the maximum dispatch performance of blocks you will find that (a) tracing would generate enormous log files, and (b) it would be very difficult to trace block dispatching without impacting performance.